# read a remote binary file with PHP stream_context_create

Tags: php, https, download

How can I download (and write locally) a binary file from a https server using PHP "stream_context_create"

Is there another simpler way (I don't want to use cURL)

Comment: $file = file_get_content("url");

Comment: Yes, but if I have to deal with https and certificate ?

Comment: it will download https unless the server blocks the request for various reasons. eg. restricted access

Comment: Nice, but the file downloaded is pretty huge, can write it chunk by chunk on disk ?

Comment: try `fopen($url, 'r')`

Comment: might be 'rb' for `read binary`